# Problems with subdivision surface on a mesh

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm new in Blender, i'm doing a dome with tow windows, but i have problems solving the boolean between the dome and the window.

When i apply the subdivision surface it goes bad, i know tehere are prblems with the topolgy.

Please, any advice? Thanks!
[image]
Bad mesh

Comment: Please show a reference image of what is your [01] desired goal and and an [02] image of how it has failed.  It is difficult to guess what is [bad] as written by you above.  Please make your question clearer.  GIMP is free software that can place to images into a larger image if BSE does not allow you to place multiple images in your question.  Perhaps you will get a quicker answer after those steps.

Comment: Hello, as I said, i'm new to blender, so i don't really know wich is the best way for a  good workflow.